# mod_rewrite strange behaviour when url with two subdirectories

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm developing a web project with php, html5 and javascript. Right now I am using php to handle the URL when the user refresh the page in order to capture the subdirectories and recalculate the content of the page (it is needed because I'm using ajax).

Ok, everithing works well on this manner, but to accomplish this I need to redirect every request to my page to index.php that calls another file called controller.php.
To do this I'm using the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /MySubDirectory/index.php [QSA]
```

I'm testing it on localhost, so for patterns following:

```
localhost/MySubDirectory/
localhost/MySubDirectory/something
```

it works, but when I add a new folder:

```
localhost/MySubDirectory/something/somethingelse
```

I get weird errors on the css and javascript imports

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-1.8.2.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < SpriteAnimation.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Bile.js:1
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What's throwing that error?  You most likely do not want to pass static resources like JavaScript files through the PHP.

Comment: I have a header.php and a footer.php which loads the typical head tag and all the content of the footer to be reusable. Is that a bad practice? And if is it... how to solve?

Comment: That's a different question and it depends on the site.  It's the simplest approach and therefore certainly not a _bad_ practice until additional complexity is warranted, but that shouldn't be discussed in this question.  Back on topic: your rewrite rules should allow your web server to serve images, js, and css directly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the rewrite rules, I'm watching things on the Internet but it looks so confused. Could you provide me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not on mod_rewrite but on the links that reference the resources. They were being taken as a relative path begining on the redirected subdirectory and this makes those resources not to be loaded.
I solve it by begining each resource (javascript, css and images) with a slash, making them absolute path and not relative as they were previously.